# Moving average for the last row of a data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, moving-average

I have a data frame with two prices and moving average(window=3) for each price:

| price1 | price2 | MA3-price1 | MA3-price2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | 10 |  |  |
| 12 | 9 |  |  |
| 20 | 15 | 16.66 | 11.33 |
| 12 | 7 | 14.66 | 10.33 |
| 4 | 9 | 12 | 10.33 |
| 6 | 4 | NaN | NaN |

I don't have the MA for the last row. How can I calculate the MA for the last row and get:

| price1 | price2 | MA3-price1 | MA3-price2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | 10 |  |  |
| 12 | 9 |  |  |
| 20 | 15 | 16.66 | 11.33 |
| 12 | 7 | 14.66 | 10.33 |
| 4 | 9 | 12 | 10.33 |
| 6 | 4 | 7.33 | 6.66 |

Comment: How are you calculating the moving average?

Comment: Previews moving averages were defined before. I have to continue the table. But when I apply df.rolling(3).mean, it doesn't work for the last row and gets the NaN until 2 next window.

Answer (score 0):

To compute "MA3-price1" and "MA3-price2" columns from "price1" and "price2", try:

```py
df[["MA3-price1", "MA3-price2"]] = df.rolling(3).mean()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   price1  price2  MA3-price1  MA3-price2
0      18      10         NaN         NaN
1      12       9         NaN         NaN
2      20      15   16.666667   11.333333
3      12       7   14.666667   10.333333
4       4       9   12.000000   10.333333
5       6       4    7.333333    6.666667
```

Comment: I have to fill just the last row of "MA3-price1" and  "MA3-price2".

Comment: @SA12 `df.rolling(3).mean()` must work for last row. Make sure you have correct numeric data in price1, price2.

Comment: It works when we start from the first row of "price" or two previous windows, if I apply it for the last row, the result is NaN until two next windows. I have the historical data and I want to calculate it just for the last row and I don't want the calculations of previous rows to be repeating.